# Is there a machine learning or NLP model to separate questions and answers in raw text?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have some raw text that has questions and answers in it.  I would like to identify which parts of the text are questions and which parts are the answers.  This seems like it would be easy, but the questions aren't necessarily terminated with question marks. The only thing I know for sure is that after a question is over the answer begins, and after the answer is over another question begins, but there is no consistent format on how many \n are included in the answers.  A question is definitely its own paragraph though.

I'm hoping for some sort of pre-trained model for this?

One possibility would be to take some existing data, manually tag each paragraph as q vs a and then use google's universal sentence encoder for each paragraph to get the 512 dimension output and then use that as the input to train a neural net or some other classification model on the labeled data.  I'm hoping to avoid this path because I don't want to manually tag a few thousand paragraphs, and after all that work, who knows if the model will have a decent classification error.

Another possibility is to use something like gpt3: feed it the entire text and just ask it what are the questions/requests.  The problem with this is that the gpt3 api is still a bit sandboxed.  I tried a sample on the gpt3 playground and it only identified 80% of the questions.

Any other suggestions?

To give you an idea, the text may look like this:

What is the name of the company?

We are Acme Inc.

How many employees are there.

There are 50 employees.

Describe a day in the life of an employee.

An employee arrives at 9am.

Then they go to the factory and make widgets for 4 hours.  After making widgets they eat lunch and then go to the QA engineer to make sure their widgets are good enough.

After QA, they write a report about how many widgets they made.

Most employees leave around 5pm.

List the pay range of your employees.

The starting salary is $22/hours.

After 1 year pay increases to $25 an hour and then increases 3% per year.

Contact information:

Acme Inc

123 Main Street

Anyplace, USA

Answer (score 0):

According to the description and the text sample that you provided, I would split this problem into 2 parts:

1. How to split the whole text
2. How to "classify" which sentence (or paragraph) is a question or an answer

I tried solving this problem using a heuristics based approach with spacy (you can use other libraries).
You can just use this technique directly or use it to build a weakly supervised dataset that you can train a classification model with (try skweak).

### Sentence Detection

This is the easy part, all you have to do is follow the details in this link https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#sbd

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp("Hi, I'm sentence number 1. Hi, I'm sentence number 2.")

for sent in doc.sents:
    print(sent.text)

# Hi, I'm sentence number 1.
# Hi, I'm sentence number 2.
```

### Question or Answer

From the sample that you shared, I can see that you want to detect questions and also imperative phrases:

- Questions: How many employees are there. To detect this type of question, you can use spacy's tag property and look for WH tokens (who, where etc...). You could use the same logic to find Subject verb inversions for example etc...
- Imperative phrases: List the pay range of your employees. To detect these cases, you can search for verbs that are the first tokens of a sentence.

Here's a small example that you can follow:

```
def is_question(sent):
    d = nlp(sent)
    token = d[0] # gets the first token in a sentence
    if token.pos_ == "VERB" and token.dep_ == "ROOT": # checks if the first token is a verb and root or not
        return True
    for token in d: # loops through the sentence and checks for WH tokens
        if token.tag_ == "WDT" or token.tag_ == "WP" or token.tag_ == "WP$" or token.tag_ == "WRB":
            return True
    return  False
```

```
doc = nlp(text)

for sent in doc.sents:
    print(sent.text.strip())
    if is_question(sent.text.strip()):
        print("is question")
    else:
        print("not a question")
    print("***")

# what is the name of the company?
# is question
# ***
# We are Acme Inc.
# not a question
# ***
# How many employees are there.
# is question
# ***
# There are 50 employees.
# not a question
```

You can apply this function on a large corpus and get a weakly annotated dataset that you can use to train a classifier or you can just use the function. But...

### Beware !!

This is a heuristic based approach, not all the results are correct for example: What a beautiful day ! 
The sentence start with a WH token but it's not a question, you fix this by checking if it ends with a question mark or not but in you corpus questions don't always end with a question mark. 
A possible solution would be, to apply this on a corpus and manually filter out these outliers.

Comment: Getting a consistent POS structure will be tricky.  Sometimes questions start off with some context: Given that acme makes widgets, describe the market opportunities going forward.  It seems like I need to make something like the regex for finding emails.. but instead for questions..

Comment: @dusty_keyboard As I mentioned in my answer above, one or two rules won't be enough. The more rules you add, the bigger the coverage. 
Once you apply these rules on a big corpus, you will get a weakly labeled dataset.
You can use that dataset to build a classification model.